# Formatting text files in bash - adding new rows, changing the sign of numbers within a column etc

Tags: bash, sed, awk, formatting

I would be very grateful to any input from you on the following issue. Apologies in advance if there one too many questions in this post.

I have text files with 3 columns (tab separated) and n rows. I would like to:

- switch rows and columns (which I have done using the script below)
- add 3 columns of zero to each row
- switch row 1 and 2
- change the sign of the numbers within the newly-set 2nd row (original 2nd column)

within one script (if possible).

Or from a file with the following format:

```
1 2 3  
1 2 3  
1 2 3  
1 2 3   
.....
```

I want to get:

```
0 0 0 2 2 2 2 ...  
0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1...  
0 0 0 3 3 3 3 ...
```

switch rows & columns:

```
awk '
{
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
     a[NR,i] = $i
}
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {
for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
    str=a[1,j]
    for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
        str=str" "a[i,j];
    }
    print str
}
}' "$WD"/grads > "$WD"/vect
```

Thank you for your help in advance.
Best,
R

Comment: When you say "change the sign of the numbers within the second column" you mean from the original columns or from the rows?

Comment: sorry, I mean change the sign of the numbers within the newly-set 2nd row (original 2nd column). thanks

Comment: That awk script with that input does not generate that output. Is that a bug you are needing help fixing or is that sample output wrong?

Comment: @EtanReisner, the script works well for switching rows and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you could do, for example:

```
awk '
  NF>n{
    n=NF
  }
  {
    A[1,NR]=-$1
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) A[i,NR]=$i
  } 
  END{
    for(i=2; i<=n; i=(i==2)?1:(i==1)?3:i+1) {
      for(j=1; j<=NR; j++) $j=A[i,j]
      print 0,0,0,$0
    }
  }
' file
```